# Alternative for setInterval in node.js for launching some functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

My application stack: Node.js, mongodb

I have a task where I need to check user last login date and if it was more than 10 days ago I should send an email. My question is what better to use for this purpose?

My first idea was to use `setTimeout` or `setInterval`, which will get all users from the database and then check `lastLoginDate` and send email. But then I realized, that it could be more than 10,000 users and it could be more cases for similar checks. Some wise people gave me an advise to use `cron-tab` to launch a process upon some time and also to use stacks for gathering chunks of users and then do some operations with these stacks (chunks). The problem is that I am not really familiar with cron (crontab) or stacks.

In which way it is better to do? What does it mean to use stacks (chunks), etc.?

Comment: you can use `node-schedule` https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule

Comment: How often do you plan on doing this check? Make sure that if you do it every day (or worse every hour), you don't send an e-mail every time. Also make sure to check that the users agreed somewhere to receive e-mails from you, and that they can unsubscribe somehow, just to avoid any potential legal issues

Comment: Ok, won't it affect my app performance? For example if I will iterate a list of users in some period of time. Won't it freeze my app? How could I separate it to some chunks?

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice npm library [agenda](https://github.com/agenda/agenda)

You can define a job that runs daily.

```
 agenda.define('SEND_REMINDER_EMAIL', async job => {
     // logic to get all users those last loggedIn is 10 days or above

     job.repeatEvery('24 hours', {
     skipImmediate: true
   });
   await job.save()
 }
```

Comment: Ok, won't it affect my app performance? For example if I will iterate a list of users in some period of time. Won't it freeze my app? How could I separate it to some chunks?